# regex for string is confusing

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there any difference between the two regexes?

```
  isFunctionKey(funKey) {
  return /^('funKey')|([01][1-9]|2[0-4])$/.test(funKey);
  }
```

and

```
 isFunctionKey(funKey) {
    return /^(funKey)|([01][1-9]|2[0-4])$/.test(funKey);
  }
```

**HINT:** Look into return statement `funkey`; one is in quotes and the other is not.

Comment: Have you tested the two to get the answer to this question?

Comment: The first one matches `'funKey'` while the second only matches `funKey`

Comment: Yes, the difference is that one matches `'funkey'` in quotes, while the other matches `funkey` without quotes.  Anything else?

Comment: Are you trying to use a variable in a pattern?!

Comment: This is so funkey.

Comment: @Pogrindis ,yes i tested it but i got confused ,that's why i opted for stackoverflow.Thank you for you attention.

Comment: @ctwheels thanks for your comments ,it was really helpful;but your linked provided didn't helped me much.Thank you very much for your attention and clearing my doubts in no time.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thank you for again clearing my doubts.Thanks alot

Comment: @RachitBhatnagar The best thing to do in this scenario, at least for starters, is to just test the regex using a tool like www.regex101.com

Comment: @revo no i was not trying to use a variable in pattern.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thank you for quick response and advice